# Run DalekJS on iOs simulator

Tags: ios, macos, dalekjs

A basic DalekJS iOs simulator test fails to launch on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1.
Error is

> Port must be greater than 0 and less than 65536. Invalid argument for
>   param callbackPort: undefined

immediately after "Running tests" message. I tried to specify port and callbackPort in Dalekfile but it does not help. Appium simulator example works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the dalek-browser-ios binding hasn't been updated to work with the current Appium & XCode version, you unfortunately need to have some patience until we have the chance to fix it.
I would invite you to open up an issue in the GitHub Repo for it, so that we can keep you updated on the process.